# Google App Engine sending mail

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

I have a domain **www.MYDOMAIN.com** , and emails for **www.MYDOMAIN.com** are hosting in Yahoo Business. I have  a Google App Engine project named **xyz.appspot.com**. I would like to send emails from my app engine project , but from **email@mydomain.com**.

Is it possible to do this without moving the hosting from yahoo to google  ? Can i send an email to **person@anydomain.com** from **email@mydomain.com** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this with a domain outside of Google but according [to this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail):

> The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender address
> must be one of the following types:
>
> -The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can
> add administrators to an application using the Administration Console.
>
> -The address of the user for the current request signed in with a
> Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address
> with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be
> on a domain managed by Google Apps.
>
> -Any valid email receiving address
> for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).
>
> -Any valid email receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com. Domain accounts are accounts outside of the Google domain with email
> addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.

You should be able to add "email@mydomain.com" as an admin and send mail. If you need to send from multiple you should be able to register the domain with Google. Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/91077?hl=en).

Comment: I am not able to understand that 'valid' means , in this context. 
If I prove to google that I own the domain , will it work? I dont want to shift the mail records from yahoo to google

Comment: Yup, there is a process (i believe there are in the links above) to associate your domain with the Google project. Once you have proven you own the domain you should be able to send emails from it.

Answer (score 1):

If workable, the easiest solution is as Ryan indicated -- add "email@mydomain.com" as an application administrator (go to Permissions in the developers console for that application and add that email, then confirm using the resulting emailed link). But, keep in mind that you'll need to have a google account setup for "email@mydomain.com" for which you can receive email and follow the link while logged in as that user (might need to use a private/incognito window if you are logged into the console as a different user than).

If this approach doesn't work in your situation (you don't have access to email@mydomain.com or you can't create a google account with that email address), the path of least resistance might be to use a third party system such as SendGrid. You can see info at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendgrid about using SendGrid with GAE.

We found that to be a more flexible and simpler approach (once you do it the first time), as the requirement for creating, validating, and updating application permissions for every "from" address was too cumbersome in our situation.